# scp file with spaces in it

Tags: ssh, unix

I have a file called test file.txt on machine 1(windows). I am trying to get this file over

scp to machine 2(Linux).

> setenv fileName "test file.txt"
>
> scp user1@machine1:C:\Folder\$fileName /path/some

Please not that i have also tried with

> scp user1@machine1:C:\Folder\\"$fileName\" /path/some

In any case i the Linux terminal is throwing errors by expecting multiple files 'test' and 'file'.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the file name in a variable won't work since it gets expanded when you use it.

If it were a Linux machine you would need to quote the filename and escape the space - quote it so the local machine passes the string to scp properly, and escape it so the remote machine knows the correct file path. For example, on Linux you would do something like `scp user1@machine1:"C:\Folder\test\ file.txt" /path/some`.

For the same reason, `scp user1@machine1:"'C:\Folder\test file.txt'" /path/some` works the same way.

On Windows of course the backslash is used as a separator, so if the former doesn't work, try the latter.